# MySQL choose Unique Index instead of Single Column Index

Tags: mysql

I have tables that has index
[image]

When I search with select * from participant_site_country where study_id = 'xxx', why it choose the uindex (unique) instead of single column index (which in no 4)? Should the unique index is choosen if we do select query like 'where study_id='xxx' and partiicipant_id = 'yyy'?

Comment: @Strawberry : didn't you mean "your *study_id* index is redundant" ?

Comment: This topic is widely discussed. Essentially, given that study_id is the first column in the composite index, your study_id index is redundant.